# Newline in authors list using MNRAS package

Tags: formatting, templates, author

How do you create a linebreak / newline in a long authors list using the MNRAS (formerly mn2e) package?

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `\newauthor` command like you would use a linebreak (`\\`), i.e.:

```
\title[]{An overrunning Author Line}
\author[]{Donald Knuth$^{1,2}$\thanks{E-mail:knuthy@knuth.org},
    Leslie Lamport$^{3,2}$,
    Frank Mittelbach$^{4,2}$,
    \newauthor
    Helmut Kopta$^{5,2}$,
    Hundreds of Others
\\
$^{1}$ Harvard University, Center for Astrophysics \\
$^{2}$ University of Copenhagen, DARK Cosmology Centre \\
}
```

[image]